# Will Glade 3.12 work for Ubuntu 11.10 using Unity...no Gnome 3

Tags: 11.10, gtk, quickly, gtk3, glade

I'm in the process of learning 'Quickly' and noticed that it only has 'Glade 3.8.0' and I like to keep all my apps fully up to date. I noticed however on the gnome.org site it said that 'Glade 3.12' has to be used with 'GTK+3'. Can I install 'GTK+3' on 'Oneiric' without using any of that 'Gnome 3' nonsense or what?

Thank you!

Comment: Glade 3.12 is what quickly uses on 12.04, I just checked.

Comment: Hmmm....I think I just realized that it is the app 'Quickly' that uses 3.8.0 because I also have 'Glade 3.10' as well.?

Comment: If you're on 12.04 quickly uses 3.12 end of story

Comment: Okay, thank you! Maybe someone wants to put that as an answer so that I can close this thread then...pretty please....I lack the privileges to do so at this time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On 12.04 quickly uses glade 3.12
[image: quickly]

Comment: np.  we all try.